# Is there a quick way to derive Ord for a struct which depends only on a single field?

Tags: rust

In Rust, it is possible to derive `Ord` for a `struct`, assuming that all the elements implement or derive `Ord` themselves.

I am working with a structure which contains a "timestamp" (`DateTime`) field, and I would like to insert those structs into a `BTreeSet` such that the structs (events) are time ordered.

Hence, it would be convenient to be able to derive `Ord`, but constrained just to a single field - the timestamp.

Is this possible, or do I have to implement `Ord` myself, manually?

It should not be possible to have simultaneous events, hence a `BTreeSet` is a suitable container for this problem. (Although typically something like a BinaryHeap, or some other structure which permits duplicates, might be used instead.)

Comment: There's no way to do this with the built-in derive macro. There might be a third-party crate that implements this, but I don't know of one. The implementation should be very compact anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is no easy way to do this, the implementation is relatively short.

```
struct Event {

    timestamp: DateTime<Utc>
    // other fields ...
}

impl PartialOrd for Event {

    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<std::cmp::Ordering> {
        
        self.timestamp.partial_cmp(&other.timestamp)
    }
}

impl Ord for Event {

    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> std::cmp::Ordering {
        self.timestamp.cmp(&other.timestamp)
    }
}
```

Or, as described in the comment below:

```
impl PartialOrd for Event {

    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<std::cmp::Ordering> {
        
        Some(self.cmp(other))
    }
}
```

---

Also as noted by others, if we define a custom implementation of `PartialOrd` which depends on a single field, for consistency we should define also `PartialEq`.

```
// For Eq we just mark that our type has this
impl Eq for Event { }

impl PartialEq for Event{

    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        
        self.timestamp.eq(&other.timestamp)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simplify this code (in the general case) and reduce the risk of mistakes by having your `PartialOrd` implementation call `Ord`: `Some(self.cmp(other))`.

Answer (score 2):

The library [`derivative`](https://crates.io/crates/derivative) offers alternative derive macros which support ignoring fields. I haven't used it myself, but this seems to generate the desired code:

```rust
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};
use derivative::{Derivative};

#[derive(Derivative)]
#[derivative(PartialOrd, Ord, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct Event {
    timestamp: DateTime<Utc>,
    
    #[derivative(PartialOrd="ignore", PartialEq="ignore", Ord="ignore")]
    foo: f64,
}
```

Note that if you ignore a field in `PartialOrd`, then the `PartialEq` and `Ord` implementations *must* do the same — as specified in the documentation of [`PartialOrd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html) and [`Ord`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html). It would be nice if `derivative` respected that automatically, but it does not seem to.

Comment: From the latter part of your answer, I take it that my answer is missing two additional things. Implementations of `Eq` and `PartialEq` ? If that is correct, what is the reason as to why these are required? I would **guess** that some standard algorithms expect ordering and equality to be defined in a compatible way, which in this case requires that they be defined as operations using the same set of fields in the same order. Does the query make sense?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant The language design as a whole considers that `PartialEq` should provide a subset of the functionality of `PartialOrd`. For example, the `<` and `>` operators call `PartialOrd`, and the `==` operator calls `PartialEq` — there is no “ordered-equal” operator separate from “regular-equal”. But regardless of that — when you see a requirement in a trait's documentation, you obey that requirement when implementing the trait. Otherwise, generic code may break when it encounters your type, because it assumes that property holds.